# Plotting date intervals in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset which has a bunch of date intervals (i.e. POSIXct format start dates and end dates).

In the example provided, let's say it's each period is associated to when someone was in school or out of school. I'm interested in plotting the data in ggplot2, each row is essentially data for one period. Currently all of the rows don't have a factor variable, but I've put one in the example as it may make things easier to plot. It's worth noting that in some cases the end date of one period and the beginning of the next overlap.

In the data, each row is a unique stint in school associated to a specific period. I'm interested in creating a sequence of weeks (from the first week to the last week in dataset) in the x axis and on the y axis I want just either a dot for each week to signify whether the person was in school (also identifying which stint) or out of school (even a gap perhaps would suffice). Thus perhaps an 8 level factor is needed in this case, one for each period, and a level for out of school (or perhaps no level is needed for when out of school)?

So in this case we could envisage having 7 rows of dots on the y axis, something (very loosely) like this (this example has many gap in lines, but I expect few or no gaps).

[image]

I envisaged the process to be something like: create a sequence from min(start_date) to max(end_date), join rows to this. Then somehow identify each period and create a factor variable for each period. Then plot the factor variable (e.g. period1, period2, period3) against the sequence of dates. I haven't been able to do this though as it's quite fiddly.

Looking at the lubridate package I was thinking that using interval() and %within% might be the solution but I wasn't sure.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
                              
start_dates = ymd_hms(c("2019-05-08 00:00:00",
                        "2020-01-17 00:00:00",
                        "2020-03-03 00:00:00",
                        "2020-05-28 00:00:00",
                        "2020-12-10 00:00:00",
                        "2021-05-07 00:00:00",
                        "2022-01-04 00:00:00"), tz = "UTC")
  
end_dates = ymd_hms(c( "2019-10-24 00:00:00",
                       "2020-03-03 00:00:00", 
                       "2020-05-28 00:00:00",
                       "2020-12-10 00:00:00",
                       "2021-05-07 00:00:00",
                       "2022-01-04 00:00:00",
                       "2022-01-19 00:00:00"), tz = "UTC") 

df = data.frame(studying = paste0("period",seq(1:7),sep = ""),start_dates,end_dates)
```

Comment: do you mean? `df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = start_dates, xend = end_dates, y =studying, yend = studying, color = studying)) + 
   geom_segment(size=3)`

Comment: mmm.....I knew it was going to be a simple fix! I think it looks good. But instead of segment could you maybe have a point for each week? That will make it easier to spot where things might be overlapping or going wrong (thus the actual data needs to be binned by week and a dot/or not placed for that week).

Comment: So I think it needs to be binned by weekly periods perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
df %>% 
  ggplot() + 
   geom_segment(aes(x = start_dates, xend = end_dates, y =studying, yend = studying, color = studying), size=3) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = start_dates, xend = start_dates, y =0, yend = studying))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = end_dates, xend = end_dates, y =0, yend = studying))
```

[image]

Per wwek as you asked in the comments

```
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(start = week(start_dates),
         end = week(end_dates)) %>% 
  mutate(gr = start>end, 
         start_2 = ifelse(gr, 0, NA),
         end_2 = ifelse(gr, end, NA),
         end = ifelse(gr, 52, end)) %>% 
  select(-2:-3, -gr) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  separate(col = name, into = c("name", "index"), sep = "_", fill = "right") %>%  
  mutate(index = ifelse(is.na(index), 1, index)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=studying , yend=studying , x=start, xend=end, color=studying)) + 
   geom_segment(size = 2)
```

[image]

To get overlaps you can use the `valr` package. Since it is developed to find overlaps in DNA segments the data needs some transformation. Start end end are calculated using a cumsum week approach. Chrom is set to `"1"`.

```
library(valr)
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(start = week(start_dates) + (year(start_dates)-min(year(start_dates)))*52,
         end = week(end_dates) + (year(end_dates)-min(year(end_dates)))*52,
         chrom="1", 
         index=1:n()) %>%  
  valr::bed_intersect(., .) %>% 
  filter(studying.x != studying.y) %>% 
  # filter duplicated intervals out
  mutate(index = paste(index.x, index.y) %>% str_split(., " ") %>% map(sort) %>% map_chr(toString)) %>% 
  filter(duplicated(index))

# A tibble: 5 x 15
  studying.x start_dates.x end_dates.x start.x end.x chrom index.x studying.y start_dates.y end_dates.y start.y end.y index.y .overlap index
  <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int> <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <int>    <int> <chr>
1 period3       1583193600  1590624000      61    74 1           3 period2       1579219200  1583193600      55    61       2        0 2, 3 
2 period4       1590624000  1607558400      74   102 1           4 period3       1583193600  1590624000      61    74       3        0 3, 4 
3 period5       1607558400  1620345600     102   123 1           5 period4       1590624000  1607558400      74   102       4        0 4, 5 
4 period6       1620345600  1641254400     123   157 1           6 period5       1607558400  1620345600     102   123       5        0 5, 6 
5 period7       1641254400  1642550400     157   159 1           7 period6       1620345600  1641254400     123   157       6        0 6, 7
```

Comment: This is great. However, if I did want to plot each week instead of the ribbon. How would I do it? I'll accept the above answer but I would really like to know this as well?

Comment: Do you mean week 1 to 52 independet of the year?

Comment: So basically, in the plot for each interval bin by week and have a point present or absent if studying across the three year time series. I know it would be a lot on the x axis but I really want to know how to do it. It just splits the ribbons by week and has a point.

Comment: Also having issue with dependency of valr... package ‘rtracklayer’ is not available for this version of R

Comment: just install the package https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rtracklayer.html

Comment: Sorry! I don't think I explained it properly. So, the points should still be relative to the year in which they are in. Thus it's exactly the same as the first figure you have (same order), but instead of having year on xaxis there is weeks and instead of being a ribbon on y axis there is a point for each week (currently it's all joined up, but I wanted binned per week with one point present/absent). I can't attach an image here unfortunately.

Comment: Why should points be better? But ok, try `df %>% 
  group_by(studying) %>% 
  do(data.frame(week=seq(.$start_dates,.$end_dates,by="1 week"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = studying, x=week)) + 
   geom_point()`